# Sitecore rendering not found intermittently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, rendering, sitecore-mvc

We have a page with various renderings on it. This page loads fine intermittently. One day it will work without any issues and the other day it stops working completely. When it stops working completely, the issue is

```
 Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
    Message: The view 'renderingname.cshtml' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/News/renderingname.aspx
~/Views/News/renderingname.ascx
~/Views/Shared/renderingname.aspx
~/Views/Shared/renderingname.ascx
~/Views/News/renderingname.cshtml
~/Views/News/renderingname.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/renderingname.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/renderingname.vbhtml
```

The route has been registered properly before the OOTB route. The other views on the page never have this problem which reside in the same directory as renderingname.cshtml.

Here is the controller code running this component without the model code -

```
public ActionResult GetComponent()
{
    //code to populate the model

    return View("renderingname", model);
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: are you using controller rendering ? can you please show me the code for your action that return the view ?

Comment: Yes using a controller rendering. I'll post code later on.

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: Looks like the rendering cannot be found. What's the name of the Controller? If you don't specify a path for your view it will try and find it based on the name of the controller or in shared.

Comment: @Ian .. the rendering lives under a path which is registered. All other renderings work fine in the same rendering with the same controller.

Comment: Do you have the rendering in source control?  Is it the same name?  when does it start throwing this error?  After a deployment or something? :)

Comment: It is in TFS and is the same name as one expected by the controller action. The error happens randomly. We just deployed this code in production and sometimes it works on 1 CD, 2 CDs or CM only. Also, this code works fine in 2 other environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the full path for your rendering :

```
public ActionResult GetComponent()
{
    //code to populate the model
    return View("~/Views/Your_View_Folder/renderingname.cshtml",model);
}
```